# GMail SMTP test mail sending failed

Tags: php, wordpress, testing, smtp, gmail

[image: smtp_error]

This image above shows the error: SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)

But my GMail SMTP settings are correct and working. How is this possible?

Comment: Try with changing the port to 587.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: It returned me lots of error when I switched the port to 587, as well as TLS.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail SMTP (smtp.gmail.com) use the port **587** and need a **secured** connection.
Otherwise it seems Google SMTP has restricted its use to Google G Suite subscriber.
You have these information and a test tool at https://www.smtper.net

I have tested myself with my G Suite mail, the test tool works great.